# Debugging in VS Code does not work for Typescript Vue app

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I generated a new Vue app out of the box like this:

```
? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Choose Vue version, Babel, TS, PWA, Router, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter, Unit, E2E
? Choose a version of Vue.js that you want to start the project with 3.x (Preview)
? Use class-style component syntax? Yes
? Use Babel alongside TypeScript (required for modern mode, auto-detected polyfills, transpiling JSX)? Yes
? Use history mode for router? (Requires proper server setup for index fallback in production) Yes
? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): Sass/SCSS (with dart-sass)
? Pick a linter / formatter config: Prettier
? Pick additional lint features: Lint on save, Lint and fix on commit
? Pick a unit testing solution: Jest
? Pick an E2E testing solution: WebdriverIO
? Pick browsers to run end-to-end test on Chrome
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, ESLint, etc.? In dedicated config files
? Save this as a preset for future projects? No
```

Added a launch.json to VS Code like this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Added a vue.config.js to my project root like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

Put a breakpoint in main.ts at:

```js
createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

Ran `npm run serve` from the command line and hit F5 in VS Code. No break. How can I troubleshoot this? Is Typescript just not suitable for Vue? I've had JS projects work before.

Comment: The sourceMapOverrides section is where alot of people solve this, I needed a period before the src like \\\.\src, I think looking at the webpack source file tree in the browser will tell you what “folders” it’s using.

Comment: "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*" }

Comment: A little bit late but hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760994/how-to-debug-a-vuejs-3-typescript-project-with-vs-code-and-chrome-using-sourcema) answer works for you too.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, none of the other answers worked for me.  Maybe it was because I was using Single File Components (SFC) and they were not?

After spending hours digging into this problem, I think I've found out where it stems from:

During the build process, Vue will split your SFCs into their individual parts (`<template>`, `<script>`, and `<style>`) and run those parts through the appropriate loaders.

When your SFCs use TypeScript, the `<script>` portion of those SFCs are compiled using the TypeScript Compiler (TSC).  The problem is that the TSC has no idea that the code it is compiling actually originated from your SFC, because all it sees is the content from the `<script>` portion **after** it has been segregated by the Vue compiler.

Because of this, the TSC generates Source Maps that contain improper line numbers (they are not shifted down to compensate for the `<template>` portion of you SFC), improper source file references (the filenames contain hashes that are placed there by the Vue compiler), and improper source file content (the content will contain the `<script>` code **only** and will be missing the `<template>` and `<style>` code).

Unfortunately, I can't describe how to fix the problem here, as it would make this post ***very*** long, but I can redirect you to a [blog post](https://ckhconsulting.com/vue-typescript-debuggers/) I wrote about the topic.

In short, the way I fixed the problem was by leveraging the Webpack build process to correct the broken Source Maps.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer in your blog! This was driving me crazy and your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Also confirmed you can use vscode's built-in browser debugger instead of the deprecated chrome debugger extension. Just change the type in your launch.json from "chrome" to "pwa-chrome."

Comment: @EricBynum you're welcome!  I'm glad it helped.  You'll notice that one of the comments on my blog mentions that it doesn't play very well with Module Hot Reloading.  I haven't had a chance to look into why that is, nor have I had time to look into how to fix it, but I would like to find a solution at some point in the future.

Comment: While I have succeeded with it for the most part, it seems like it doesn't support `script setup` style of Vue 3. If I define the following template/script in my vue file: `<template><button @click="updatecount">{{ count }}</button></template>` and `<script setup lang="ts">import { ref } from "vue";
let count = ref(0); function updatecount() { count.value++; console.log("updated"); }</script>` and place breakpoints on `count.value++` line, the breakpoints get hit as soon as I refresh the page, but not on actual click, even when the count is updated. Any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: Digging it further, I have succeeded with it, but using a strange fix. In the article where you add the following line in vue.config.js: `line: originalLine + indexOfScriptTag`, I had to replace it with `line: originalLine + indexOfScriptTag - 4`. I have found that this magic number works for `script setup` syntax, whereas for normal vue 3 syntax (`export default defineComponent...`), I have to do `line: originalLine + indexOfScriptTag - 1`. My gut feeling is that these magic numbers are not needed and there is some small issue in the `vue.config.js` code, but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Jeff, thank you for your blog post, it explained a gap with other solutions I had. Here's an improvement: use "/.*\n/g" instead of "/.+\n/g" to split by lines to account for empty lines (e.g. between </template> and <script>). @dotNET I think this might solve some of your issues.

However I still get many breakpoints in a different place (either in a shifted line or a shifted column). In some places it works fine. Anybody else experiencing this?

I did add the "webpack://<name-in-package.json>/src/*" sourceMapRewrite. Any way to further debug this?

Comment: @ManuelKammermann:  Thanks. A bit of time has passed since I came here and I have since switched to Vite + TypeScript + Composition API. Life is so much better with this stack compare to webpack and Vue CLI. All breakpoints hit properly and all other debugging features work too. If you're reading it at the end of 2023, you should consider switching too.

Comment: Hi, @dotNET I am totally considering this. I assume the issues with JS Debugger come from the fact, that SFC using <script setup> undergo an additional transformation in vue-loader to generate an options object version of it, which is then passed to webpack (https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/compiler-sfc/src/compileScript.ts). Webpack doesn‘t know about this, and my guess is, that there‘s missing mappings.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the snippet below for your `sourceMapPathOverrides`

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*.vue": "${webRoot}/*.vue",
        "webpack:///./src/*.ts": "${webRoot}/*.ts",
     }
```

Comment: This answer helped me. In my case I was trying to hit breakpoints in .js mixin files. So I added `"webpack:///./src/*.js": "${webRoot}/*.js"` to `sourceMapPathOverrides` in my launch.json file

Answer (score 2):

Follow this recipe and it should solve your problem - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/vuejs-cli

Your launch.json needs to look more like this (omit the preLaunchTask unless you define it in tasks.json):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "pathMapping": {
        "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "vuejs: start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you! this worked for me when nothing else was working. i also have to have this in the vue.config.js:
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple solutions, this was the only one that worked. [author ref](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2897#issuecomment-788952677)

I just put this in *vue.config.js* and my debug finally worked.

```
/* eslint-disable */
const CompilerSfc = require('@vue/compiler-sfc')
const parse = CompilerSfc.parse
CompilerSfc.parse = (source, options) => {
    return parse(source, Object.assign({ pad: true }, options))
}

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: (info) => {
                if (info.allLoaders === '') {
                    // when allLoaders is an empty string the file is the original source
                    // file and will be prefixed with src:// to provide separation from
                    // modules transpiled via webpack
                    const filenameParts = ['src://']
                    if (info.namespace) {
                        filenameParts.push(info.namespace + '/')
                    }
                    filenameParts.push(info.resourcePath.replace(/^\.\//, ''))
                    return filenameParts.join('')
                } else {
                    // otherwise we have a webpack module
                    const filenameParts = ['webpack://']
                    if (info.namespace) {
                        filenameParts.push(info.namespace + '/')
                    }
                    filenameParts.push(info.resourcePath.replace(/^\.\//, ''))
                    const isVueScript =
                        info.resourcePath.match(/\.vue$/) &&
                        info.query.match(/\btype=script\b/) &&
                        !info.allLoaders.match(/\bts-loader\b/)
                    if (!isVueScript) {
                        filenameParts.push('?' + info.hash)
                    }
                    return filenameParts.join('')
                }
            },
        },
    },
}
```